# Best way to use multiple custom fonts in Flutter web without increasing app size/initial load time

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have flutter web application and there almost 25+ fonts need to be used ,
all font folder size more than 35mb so please suggest me best way to implement all font with consuming memory

Comment: You might be able to make the fonts smaller by removing glyphs you're not using. A tool like fontforge could do this. Or if they're commonly used fonts on the internet you could try linking to CDN versions, so that there would be a good chance a browser would already have them cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can user google font package if those fonts are available in google fonts.

[google font flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts)

if you are trying to use icons as a fonts like font awesome or other custom font libraries download those libraries as SVG and discard unused icons then use  IcoMoon to generate custom font. using that you can also download dart font mappings to use in your app
[IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/app/)